# get value of a dropdown using plain javascript from a dynamically generated row

Tags: javascript

I have been stuck here for hours now. I need to get what value is selected in the dropdown after button clicked.All the rows are dynamically generated like this image. [image: all the rows are dynamically generated]

I can get the child node and the html but can't get the selected value. My code so far.

```
 var parent_element=e.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling;
 var selected_element = parent_element.childNodes[1].getElementsByClassName('selectpicker');
    console.log(selected_element);
```

Html stucture. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
<div class="col-md-12 neighbourhood-data neighbour-2">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-2">
           <select name="" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true">
                <option value="">--Select One--</option>
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
                <option value="4">Four</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Distance">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-info" onclick="getDistanceLocation(this)">Get distance from google</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                     <div class="row text-center">
                         <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="checkbox">
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-2">
                             <input type="checkbox">
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-2">
                             <input type="checkbox">
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-2">
                             <input type="checkbox">
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-2">
                             <input type="checkbox">
                         </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger neighbourhood-remove-button">Remove</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: I can't provide id here cause there will be multiple rows with the same elements. I have to get the value on after button is clicked inside that row.

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = selected_element.options[selected_element.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: tried that already, but getting uncaught typeerror. can't read property of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You just need the value property from the element. Here's a light example:

```js
function getValue () {
  var el = document.querySelector('#selecty'),
      val = el.value;
  alert("You picked: " + val)
}
```

```html
<select id='selecty'>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<button onclick="getValue()">What did I pick?</button>
```

Comment: Can't use id here, there will be multiple rows with the same elements as the row is dynamically generating. I have changed user code to this.

     var val = e.querySelector('.selectpicker'),
            val = val.value;
        alert("You picked: " + val);

But getting 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: Doesn't matter how you retrieve the element, the ID was just an example. But sounds like your selector didn't work, are you sure you added the appropriate class there?

Comment: you need to do `val.options[selected_element.selectedIndex].value` because the `val` variable contains the `<select>` and not the selected value.

Comment: @KevinKloet thanks a lot. works just fine. Wondering why I didn't think that.

Comment: had to remove getElementsByClassName('selectpicker') from second line. then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Working logic example.

```js
    $("#btnClick").click(function () {
            var selectedOption = $("select option:selected");
            alert(selectedOption.val());
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="btnClick" value='click to get value' />
```